# Running Pulse Schedules with different resilience levels

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

Is there a way to run a Pulse schedule with different resilience levels? I was thinking about passing the resilience level values in the options of Sampler primitive, but when I tried to run, it says Pulse Schedule is not supported, getting the below error:

```
QpyError: "Object type '<class 'qiskit.pulse.schedule.Schedule'>' is not supported in Program namespace."
```

Is there any other way to run my Pulse schedule with ZNE or M3 error mitigation strategy?